# Azure CloudBlob StartCopy method between 2 storage accounts - 404 Error

Tags: c#, azure, copy, http-status-code-404, azure-blob-storage

So I've been going through the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/copy-blobs-from-command-line-and-code/7-move-blobs-using-net-storage-client tutorial and am trying to copy blobs from one storage account to another storage account (both accounts are run locally on my computer as a local development environment emulator via Azurite). Trying to learn more about Azure SDK with C#.

I am able to connect to both accounts no problem and my program so far can upload/download blob files and create containers. However, it appears that when I execute my program in Visual Studio, it would reach the line that contains StartCopy (or StartCopyAsync) and throw a web exception: 404 Not Found error. Within the exception, when I expand the RequestInformation, the ErrorCode is "ContainerNotFound" and the HttpStatusMessage is "The specified container does not exist." Not sure why I am getting those messages since I can verify that the containers exist and just for heck of it, I prepopulated the source and destination azure storages with the files and containers beforehand just to see what happened. Unfortunately, the same error. I then tried setting the public accesss level of the container and blobs to be public. Unfortunately, that was a no go as well. What should happen is that it should just copy the blob file from source to destination and that would be the end of that.

At first, I thought maybe I didn't configure something right but that doesn't seem to be the case or at least I thought? Then I tried copying files between 1 local storage account emulator to an actual online Azure storage (student) account thru Microsoft and that did not work as well.  I was able to copy between 2 containers within the same account so that part wasn't an issue but trying to copy between 2 different accounts has been making me "banging my head for a few hours now".

Code should be quite similar to how it was done in Microsoft's tutorial as mentioned in the first link in this post. Not exactly sure why I keep getting this 404 error. Turned off my firewall temporarily in case that was causing trouble but that did not make a difference. I also tried someone else's code (though had to modify it slightly to work in my case) and I'm still running into the same issue. So perhaps, maybe there is something wrong with my setup here?

In the console of my Azurite local servers, I can see server 2 (destination server for the Copy process) has:

Local Source Server

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2021:23:28:39 +0000] "PUT /devstoreaccount1/source/NewBlob HTTP/1.1" 201 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2021:23:28:39 +0000] "HEAD /devstoreaccount1/source/NewBlob HTTP/1.1" 200 0
```

Local Destination Server

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2021:23:28:39 +0000] "PUT /devstoreaccount1/destination/NewBlob HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Code:

```
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string storageKey = "AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=<MY_ACCOUNT_KEY_GOES_HERE>;DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;";

            string storageKey2 = "AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=<MY_ACCOUNT_KEY_GOES_HERE>;DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10100/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10101/devstoreaccount1;";

            // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageKey);
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount2 = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageKey2);

            //create client from storage account
            CloudBlobClient sourceClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobClient sourceClient2 = storageAccount2.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            //declare source container and create if doesn't exist
            CloudBlobContainer sourceContainer = sourceClient.GetContainerReference("source");
            await sourceContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

            //upload local file to azurite 1
            CloudBlockBlob uploadBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("NewBlob");
            await uploadBlob.UploadFromFileAsync("NewBlob");

            // designate source blob as the new uploaded file
            ICloudBlob sourceBlob = await sourceContainer.GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync("NewBlob");

            //declare destination container and create it if it doesn't exist
            CloudBlobContainer destBlobContainer = sourceClient2.GetContainerReference("destination");
            await destBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

            //start copy process of blob between 2 servers
            CloudBlockBlob destBlob = destBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(sourceBlob.Name);
            await destBlob.StartCopyAsync(new Uri(GetSharedAccessUri(sourceBlob.Name, sourceContainer)));

            // Display the status of the blob as it is copied
            ICloudBlob destBlobRef = await destBlobContainer.GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync(destBlob.Name);
            while (destBlobRef.CopyState.Status == CopyStatus.Pending)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Blob: {destBlobRef.Name}, Copied: {destBlobRef.CopyState.BytesCopied ?? 0} of  {destBlobRef.CopyState.TotalBytes ?? 0}");
                await Task.Delay(500);
                destBlobRef = await destBlobContainer.GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync(destBlobRef.Name);
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Blob: {destBlob.Name} Complete");

        }

        // Create a SAS token for the source blob, to enable it to be read by the StartCopyAsync method
        private static string GetSharedAccessUri(string blobName, CloudBlobContainer container)
        {
            DateTime toDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60);

            SharedAccessBlobPolicy policy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy
            {
                Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
                SharedAccessStartTime = null,
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = new DateTimeOffset(toDateTime)
            };

            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
            string sas = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy);

            return blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + sas;
        }


Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: I tested your code on my side on local and Azure cloud and everything works for me as excepted. The only thing I modified is changing code : await uploadBlob.UploadFromFileAsync("NewBlob");  to await uploadBlob.UploadFromFileAsync("<my local file path>");

Comment: Thanks for checking. Maybe what I'll do is try testing it on another computer and see if that could make a difference.

Comment: Welcome, let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Hi @Rocketboy235, how's going? Has your issue got solved ?

Comment: Unfortunately still unresolved so I may have to do some experimenting and some more trial and error

Comment: So apparently it works fine if I copy the blob from 1 storage account to another when both storage accounts are through Microsoft Azure online. I'm stilll unsure why the Azurite local servers were causing issues though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, your code works perfectly on Azure cloud, maybe this is just a bug of local storage emulator. Anyway, I think your issue has been solved.I'll make a summary below, please accept it so that it will close this question. If you have any further questions about storage, pls feel to let me know:) Hope you have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code above works on Azure Cloud perfectly and I also tested your code on my local based on Storage Emulator too. I can't find out the root reason based on your code logic, it is all right.

Anyway, seems your issue has been solved on Azure Cloud, I assume this is due to some bug of the local storage emulator.